# Return type is seen as generic Object instead of required type

Tags: java, android, kotlin, kotlin-multiplatform

I my KMM project:

I have the following interop method to convert from `Single` from `Reaktive` to a `Single` from `io.reactivex.`...

```
fun <T : Any> Single<T>.asRxJava2Single(): io.reactivex.Single<T> =
    object : io.reactivex.Single<T>() {
        override fun subscribeActual(observer: io.reactivex.SingleObserver<in T>) {
            this@asRxJava2Single.subscribe(observer.asReaktiveSingleObserver())
        }
    }
```

...and for this method which is places in the shared module...

```
fun getAssignedBooks(): SingleWrapper<List<String>> {
    return singleFromCoroutine {
        bookRepository.callAssignedBooks()
    }
        .subscribeOn(ioScheduler)
        .observeOn(mainScheduler)
        .onErrorReturn { t ->
            Console.apiError.log("getAssignedBooks :: " + t.message)
            listOf()
        }
        .wrap()
}
```

...when I apply the interop method on the Android side...

```
.flatMap( pair ->
                        SingleInteropKt.asRxJava2Single(
                                new SharedBookService().getAssignedBooks()
                        ).map( list ->
                                new Pair<>(pair, (List<String>)list)// !!!!: Why need cast ?!                            )
) .flatMap(pair -> ..... //Here, pair.second is seen as Object if I don't manually cast above
//.....
```

... I need to specifically cast it to `List<String>` otherwise it sees it as `Object`. I tried to do `SingleInteropKt.asRxJava2Single<List<String>>(...)` and other variants like that but it doesn't work.

Any idea how I can make it work without a cast?

This specific case allows for specific casting, but I have another case where I need to link multiple `rxJava` method and that's where this "manual" casting doesn't work anymore.

Comment: I couldn't reproduce the issue. Would you be able to provide a complete reproducer code?

Comment: hmm, unless I write something from scratch ... i don't see how. Quick google meetup session ? :))
I'll think about it and get back to you ...